# Laravel 5: Unable to pass data to controller via redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redirect

I am trying to pass a query builder to view and I want to print it. Query builder does not return `null`, but I am unable to pass it or print it.

Controller

```
public function search() {
    $option1 = Request::get( 'option1' );
    $option2 = Request::get( 'option2' );
    $condition = Request::get( 'condition' );
    $date_option = Request::get( 'dateOption' );
    $option1_value = Request::get( 'option1_value' );
    $option2_value = Request::get( 'option2_value' );
    $fromDate = Request::get( 'fromDate' );
    $toDate = Request::get( 'toDate' );

    if ( $condition == 'no' ) {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with( 'brand', 'section', 'representive', 'buyer', 'seller', 'buyingPaymentType', 'sellingPaymentType' )->where( $option1, $option1_value )->get();
        //return $vehicle;
    }
    if ( $condition == 'or' ) {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with( 'brand', 'section', 'representive', 'buyer', 'seller', 'buyingPaymentType', 'sellingPaymentType' )->where( $option1, $option1_value )->orWhere( $option2, $option2_value )->get();
    }
    if ( $condition == 'and' ) {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with( 'brand', 'section', 'representive', 'buyer', 'seller', 'buyingPaymentType', 'sellingPaymentType' )->where( $option1, $option1_value )->where( $option2, $option2_value )->get();
    }

    return  redirect()->back()->with( 'vehicles', $vehicles );
    //return $vehicles;
}
```

View

```
@if(isset($vehicles))
    @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
        <td>{{ $vehicle->id }}</td>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m struggling to see what you’re trying to do. If you’re trying to build a search form and display results, use a GET route instead, that way you don’t have to redirect, the URL can be bookmarked etc.

Comment: @MartinBean, OP is trying to pass additional data with the redirect. which may or may not have been part of the form submitted data. Imagine you're logging in a user, and if successful, you're passing some additional data besides the `user` object (for example, the `vehicle` objects associated with that `user`) to the next page.

Comment: @ArmanH It looks like a search form to me, building up a query based on passed options. If it were a login form, ignoring it has far too many fields, why wouldn’t the OP just query the database based on the authenticated user’s ID?

Comment: The specifics of this particular example don't matter to the wider question of how to pass data from controller to controller on redirects. Why is OP doing A as opposed to B, is up to him to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting using `with('vehicles', $vehicles)` on the `redirect()` method creates a `vehicles` session flash message, instead of passing your data to the next controller (see [Laravel 5.1 Redirect Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)).

[It seems that you can't send variables per se](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-redirect-with-variables), so you will have to rely on session data.

You can test if the flash message is set in your view using `session->has('vehicles')` or `session->('vehicles')` helpers:

```
@if(session()->has('vehicles')))
    {{ session('vehicles') }}
@endif
```

Since your `$vehicles` is a complex objects, you'll have to check how Laravel handles serializing it into session, and may need to unserialize it before you can loop over the items.

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation that you linked to. with() flashes the data to the session, which is often used for flash messages, but also for any other data that you wish to flash. His array will be properly serialized. As I pointed out in my answer, he just needs to read it from the session back into a variable if he wants to access it using local variables.

Comment: @Rob_vH I'm not sure where my misunderstanding is, but thanks for re-iterating 2 existing answers.

Comment: "session flash message" -- it flashes the variables to the session (which can be used for messages, but is not particularly specific to them). He can then get them back out on the other side with Session::get().  Serialization is implicit and, in this way, you can stash an array there and have it back out on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

When using redirect and with you can use Sessions

```
@if(Session::has('vehicles'))
    @foreach(Session::get('vehicles') as $vehicle)

    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while you have flashed the $vehicles array to the session (which is working as it should with your code), you are never reading it back out. I think you expect that putting something in the session will automatically put it back into a variable on the next load, but this is not the case.

Rather, you need to read the variable out of the session. Something like:

As before:

```
return  redirect()->back()->with( 'vehicles', $vehicles );
```

Then wherever the previous route is handled you can read the session and check whether it's null or not;

```
$vehicles = \Session::get('vehicles');
```

Then you can use it as you normally would. You can also access the session variables directly from Blade templates as Elvin has shown you.